# Can I give multiple url scheme for same for my iOS application?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, url-scheme

**I want to add a second URL Schemes for my application for the same target in Xcode**. After unsuccessful attempts I am trying to add through the following approach by adding the URL schemes separated by comma (,) .Is my approach correct? **Can iOS application have multiples URL schemes**?

Please find the image below:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Click on the + button under 'additional url type properties' to add a new url scheme.

The 's' in 'URL Schemes' is misleading. It does not indicates you can enter multiple schemes, but that you enter a prefix for some urls.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/allowing_apps_and_websites_to_link_to_your_content/defining_a_custom_url_scheme_for_your_app

Comment: "Click on the + button under 'additional url type properties' to add a new url scheme." can I add this for same bundle id once again?

Comment: Yes, all information you edit for a bundle plist applies to this bundle only